# An elegant way to tightly "serialise/deserialise" my class property values (via byte array)?

Tags: vb.net, serialization, deserialization

By "tight" I mean the shortest possible array of bytes.

The following Code works perfectly but I am sure it could be more elegant.
There are inefficiences in the deserialisation part as indicated in the code comments.

I do not know enough to be able to get my propertyList elements to act as reference types rather than value types.

Can ayone advise code if it is possible to do what I seek?

```
Imports System
Public Class Form1

 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim myPerson, deserialisedPerson As Person
    Dim serialisedProperties As Byte()

    myPerson = New Person("John Smith", "26")
    serialisedProperties = myPerson.Serialise

    deserialisedPerson = New Person(serialisedProperties)
 End Sub
End Class


Class Person
 Public Name As String = ""
 Public Age As Integer = 0

 Private _propertyList As New List(Of Object)
 Private _numberOfBytesList As New List(Of Integer)

 Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal age As Integer)
    Me.Age = age
    Me.Name = Left(name.PadRight(24), 24)  'strings will be truncated/padded to  24 characters
    UpdatePropertiesList()
 End Sub

 Sub New(ByVal serialisedProperties As Byte())
    'this alternative constructor deserialises the byte array
    Dim tempBytes As Byte()
    Dim byteCounter As Integer = 0
    UpdatePropertiesList()

    For index As Integer = 0 To _propertyList.Count - 1
        'load tempBytes with relevent bytes for this property
        ReDim tempBytes(_numberOfBytesList(index) - 1)
        Array.ConstrainedCopy(serialisedProperties, byteCounter, tempBytes, 0, tempBytes.Length)

        Select Case _propertyList(index).GetType.Name
            Case "String"
                _propertyList(index) = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(tempBytes).TrimEnd
                'HOW CAN WE GET PROPERTY REFERENCES INTO   _propertyList (INSTEAD OF VALUES) 
                'SO THAT THIS SINGLE LINE OF CODE WILL UPDATE     deSerialisedperson.Name FROM "" to "John Smith"?
            Case "Int32"
                _propertyList(index) = BitConverter.ToUInt32(tempBytes, 0)
                'HOW CAN WE GET PROPERTY REFERENCES INTO   _propertyList (INSTEAD OF VALUES) 
                'SO THAT THIS SINGLE LINE OF CODE WILL UPDATE     deSerialisedperson.Age FROM 0 to "26"?
            Case Else
                Beep()
        End Select
        byteCounter += _numberOfBytesList(index)
    Next

    'THESE LINES OF CODE COULD BE AVOIDED IF I COULD ACHIEVE THE ABOVE !@#
    Me.Name = _propertyList(0)
    Me.Age = _propertyList(1)
 End Sub

 Public Function Serialise() As Byte()
    Dim bytes As New List(Of Byte)

    For Each prop As Object In _propertyList
        Select Case prop.GetType.Name
            Case "String"
                bytes.AddRange(Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(CType(prop, String)))
            Case "Int32"
                bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(CType(prop, Int32)))
            Case Else
                Beep()
        End Select
    Next
    Return bytes.ToArray
 End Function

 Private Sub UpdatePropertiesList()
    _propertyList.Clear()
    _numberOfBytesList.Clear()

    _propertyList.Add(Name)
    _numberOfBytesList.Add(48) 'ie 24 unicode chars
    _propertyList.Add(Age)
    _numberOfBytesList.Add(4) 'ie int32
 End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Make your class Serializable and then use a seriallizer?

Comment: And what's wrong with what you have?  Besides this hideous `_propertyList` and `_numberOfBytesList` crap, that is...and the fact that you're basically reinventing `<Serializable()>`, badly.

Comment: Basically he means use camelCase for variables and PascalCase for method names and class definitions. Underscores are old school.

Comment: @sircodesalot: I'm not even talking about their names.  I'm talking about their very existence.  This is the kind of thing reflection is for.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. Yeah that's maybe a bit odd. I recommend taking a few minutes to learn about Serializable.

Comment: Mark your class serializable and Use binary serializer. Done

Comment: Look into ProtoBuf-NET fir a binary serializer that produces **much** smalle output than the NET BF

Comment: @Plutonix probably best to start slow and just use the serializers that come packaged with .net.

Comment: Chao, like I say, it could be done in less code if the list elements were ref types. There must be a way to do that.

Comment: sircodesalot serialisation does not appear an adequate option as it seems to pad the serialised byte array with a lot of extra overhead stuff. Pretty hard to beat 52 bytes for a 24 char string and an int32. Obviously my real code has many more properties.

Comment: Thanks to whoever tidied up the code format. I am new here and for seem reason it got jumbled when I pasted.

Comment: attention @sircodesalot

Comment: @BlueHorizon: Eh.  You only have 28 bytes' worth of data; almost half that 52 bytes is overhead.  Check out [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview).  That same object could easily take up well under 40 bytes.

Comment: @cHao protocol buffers is an interesting approach. I am not sure how you arived at 28 bytes min data for those two properties. If you look at my code comments I stated the string has to hold unicode chars as Asian glyphs must also be stored (ie CJK). I make that 52 bytes min therefore. Which is what this code does. This class gets edited as new properties get added over time. Code changes will be much less risky by new company programmers if I can get property reference types into that propertyList. Of course the parallel listOfs above is a q&d example of the principles not my actual code.

Comment: I used your example of a 24-char string and a 32-bit int, but didn't notice the part about storing Asian chars; i was assuming ASCII-compatible strings.  UTF-8 would take more info, of course, and more properties would add more still.  But a tagged format like protocol buffers would provide forward-compatibility; without it, you'd have to either add your own versioning or migrate the data every time you add a new property.

Comment: OK, after considerable research it seems this is as elegant as it gets. The only way to have changes to _propertyList directly update the Person Properties is to have the properties themselves derive from the propertyList elements.